# How to search for double spaces within <p> elements in Atom Editor?

Tags: javascript, regex, atom-editor

I'm creating a web page by copy-pasting paragraphs of a Word document. When I copy-paste, the beginning of sentences is preceded by two spaces, which I'd like to replace globally by a single space. However, I would not like this to affect my indentation, which is also by two spaces.

I'm trying to do this by using Atom's 'search with regex' feature. I'm trying to enter the expression

```
<p>.+  .+</p>
```

However, this does not produce any matches:

[image]

There should be matches, though, as illustrated by the highlighted areas within the `p` elements in a regular search for '  ':

[image]

Also, from a little experiment in the Python shell, this regular expression seems to match what I'm looking for:

```
In [8]: re.findall(r'<p>.+  .+</p>', '  <p>Foo  Bar</p>')
Out[8]: ['<p>Foo  Bar</p>']
```

It seems from Atom's documentation, though, that the search term should be a Javascript `RegExp` expression. I tried from the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to adapt this to Javascript, but so far no success. How can I make this search in Atom work?

Comment: NotePad++, works wonders for these sorts of things. Copy it in, modify, copy it out.

Comment: Note interpretation of html, ignores the doubling of spaces. So no need to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of having `<p>Foo  Bar</p>` as the sample input, the following find and replace will work:

"Find in current buffer" = `<p>(.+)  (.+)</p>`

"Replace in current buffer" = `<p>$1 $2</p>`

[image: Example inputs in Atom]

Answer (score 2):

The highlighted spaces in your image is within a `<p class="flow-text">` - that has a class attribute - and you are searching for `<p>` which doesn't include attributes. You should do this:

```
<p[^>]*>.+  .+</p>
```

However this produces a single match which you have to use capturing groups to replace two spaces with one. You may want to try a more precise approach. Search for:

```
[ ]{2,}(?=(?:(?!<p[^>]*>).)*<\/p>)
```

and replace with a single space.